# Jquery Selector

Tags: jquery, input, selector

I'm stuck here with a problem that I can't figure out.
I want to change the value of an input field with jquery.
I don't understand why it's not working.

```
<script>
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        theimg = "[name=img\\[1\\]\\[mark\\]]";

        jQuery(theimg).attr("value", '1');    
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="img[1][mark]" value="0" />
```

The fade works, but I cannot get the input fields to change their value.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? http://www.jsfiddle.net/gnarf/wBtLW/ - Are you including jQuery? Is it in [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict) mode... Try `console.log(jQuery, $)` ?

Comment: shouldn't theimg="[name=\"img[2][mark]\"]" (or use a mix of single/double quotes). I've never checked out how liberal the selection parser is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $.val() instead.

```
$(theimg).val(1);
```

Also try this for selecting the image:

```
theimg = "input[name=\"img[2][mark]\"]";
```